# rc.common not run on mac os x

Tags: macos, shell, startup

I want to run a shell script  on startup

by google ,I found that I could add shell in rc.common

so I added the code below at the end of rc.common

is it a permission problem?

```
## rc.common test ##
touch ~/test.txt
```

reboot，there is no test.txt in my user fold

when I test it in terminal manualy ，it's ok

```
ls -l /etc/rc.common
-rw-r--r--  1 guirong  wheel  1737  3 30 22:36 /etc/rc.common
```

where is the problem? my system verison is 10.7.3
is it not ran by default in os x?

Comment: Doesn't know about apple, but from a linux/unix perspective the file need to be executable: `chmod +x /etc/rc.common`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the script to be run only for the current user, you should use ~/.bashrc instead

Later edit: I misread your question. If you want something to run at startup, you should look into launchd [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/launchd.8.html)

Comment: the pb is that rc.common is not run with your user, so it's normal that you won't see test.txt in your home directory. rc.common is ran at startup, but the recommended way on OS X is to use launchd for startup stuff

Comment: thx,but the launchd seems too complicated for me
I will look into it

Comment: ok, then try to put an absolute path to your file i.e `touch /Users/myuser/test.txt` instead of `~/test.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Just as an added bit of information about what was happening; `/etc/rc.common` runs as root, so when you were touching the file at `~/test.txt` it would have been ending up in `/var/root` (the root user's home directory)