# rc.common not working OS X

Tags: bash, macos, rc

I append some script /etc/rc.common, but when restart it not create file.

```
/usr/bin/touch /Users/home/Desktop/RC.txt
/bin/pwd >> /Users/home/Desktop/RC.txt
/bin/date >> /Users/home/Desktop/RC.txt
```

Why not working?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I learn using rc.common. i want create file RC.txt on Desktop. I reboot OS, RC.txt not create on Desktop.

Comment: Does the directory `/Users/home/Desktop` exist?  I guess not.  Usually, it is `/Users/<username>/`

Comment: yes, home is my user name.

Comment: Probably you find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945745/rc-common-not-run-on-mac-os-x

Comment: You dont understand. I work on virtual machine so <username> is home.

Comment: I use absolutely path. /Users/home/Desktop exist. I can create file via terminal, but not work rc.common

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `rc.common` isn't used on startup. It exists to be sourced by deprecated startup items, which have been superseded by `launchd` daemons and agents.

Comment: You shouldn't be messing with `rc.common`. It's better to source it, or use `launchd` as mentioned.